# Python - exporting matrix with different list lenghs

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, export, line-breaks

I want to export a matrix into a .txt file. My code for the export looks like this:

```
file = open("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Output.txt", "w")
file.write("Matrix1" + "\n")
for i in range(len(mat1)):
    out_string = ""
    out_string += str(mat1[i])
    file.write(out_string)
```

My problem is that this creates line breaks in my .txt file where they should not be like this:

```
Matrix1
[-0.46957269  0.17011335 -0.47471708  0.57137096 -0.79282618  0.30592412][-0.63786411 -0.73155594 -0.42771667  0.86549777  0.88929707  0.58907694][  878.71032715  1400.89709473  1277.76208496  1393.41540527  1170.13269043
844.46856689][  878.83557129  1399.39916992  1279.01879883  1394.15820312 1169.20703125
844.88671875][ 0.98017752  0.88977867  0.38268465 -0.91065341 -0.32004485 0.53876978][-0.31741497 -0.70884681  0.01819103  0.97179461 -0.75332266 -0.247715  ]
```

Is there a way I can remove these unwanted linebreaks?

Comment: I'd recommend not putting linebreaks into your original data.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3v This is the first time I write a program like this and I'd like to read the output data. That's why I want the linebreaks.

Comment: Either your original data structure is breaking "lines" into multiple elements or those elements contain a linefeed character. Technically, it's also possible that you're just viewing the resulting file in an editor or word processor that's adding automatic line wrapping, but that would be pretty silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I still don't know the origin of my problem, I found a way to remove the linebreaks. I added:

```
out_string = out_string.replace("\n","")
```

to the end of my code, just before

```
file.write(out_string)
```